# How to do Continuous Delivery for public libraries distributing through package managers?

Tags: ios, frameworks, continuous-delivery

We have built an iOS/MacOS library, that is being used by several iOS & Mac Apps of a very big company.

The library is being distributed through Cocoapods and Carthage, the package managers for iOS and MacOS libraries.

We have pipelines set-up to build on every commit. The test suite of Unit Tests, UI Tests and Integration Tests run on every PR created.

But, we are not sure how to go-about Continuous Deployment. We cannot release on every PR Merge, as that would mean:

1. Too many versions of the library on Cocoapods.
2. If upgrading requires code changes in the apps' code, the documentation will be distributed across different versions' release notes.
3. Our library is not significant enough to dedicate engineers to upgrade frequently on the App-side.

Please help me if you have faced similar problems and what are the standard practices.

Comment: What branching strategy are you using? When you currently upload a new version to Cocoapods/Carthage, how do you mark that version in the repository so that you can find it back later when bugs are reported? What strategy are you using for assigning version numbers?

Comment: We are using Git and the developers create branches with their changes and create a Pull Request to master branch. We Tag the commit to mark a version. There is a repo that distributes the compiled library, which also uses Tags to mark versions. We use major.minor.revision format for versioning.

Comment: CD is not a best practice for all kinds of software. CD of SaaS or web apps is very good. CD of libraries will hurt everyone. If you're able to do very frequent releases, only release when there are security issues, or on a regular schedule (e.g. at most every two weeks). Give downstream users the chance to actually upgrade to the latest version. Also: get towards a state where you can provide reasonable backwards compatibility guarantees. Don't break downstream code without a very good reason.

Answer (score 1):

## Continuous Delivery

Why?

As in what is it that you hope to achieve by employing continuous delivery for this library?

Why would your clients require a build every commit/pr?

I think you are responding to a directive from on high to be **AGILE™**. Or a feeling that there is a Standard that if followed just solves everything.

## Release Management

Unfortunately this does not go away by embracing a devops model.

As you have pointed out:

- Release notes become hard to observe
- The version repository becomes very dense
- Client teams do not have the bandwidth to handle a high release cadence.

I would also add that it makes tracking version usage more difficult, and also gives a feeling of impermanence to your library.

## The Deluge

Not every build has to be released, but then where do we draw the line?

Obviously having a feature wait a full year, just screams of wasted potential. But then so days releasing every internal change that is needed but that hasn't yet produced fruit.

There are two ways to think about this: The Feature, or the Release.

## By Feature (or set of)

In this world the priority is on a set of functionality whose value is low/negative when released piecemeal, but high when released together. This is particularly true if users have to be retrained, of business process has to be updated.

In this case it is better to have the library developed along one or more streams. When a stream is viable it is delivered into master, producing an official build. The builds off of the stream's branch are themselves built, but never delivered (or delivered to a test service, not released publicaly).

This does have the potential for making big bang merges, but on the other hand allows your CI pipeline to just release every build off of master.

## By Release (at this time)

In this world the priority is on setting expectations of updates with the clients. This is when the clients have to expend effort to ensure they are upgraded and compatible. It is sometimes called a release train, if the change isn't ready yet it misses the train.

Usually you will want to provide two variants of your library under this model. An LTS variant (stable api, bug fixes, maybe very stable additive changes) and a current variant (all of the changes, including removed/altered api calls). You may even want to run an old lTS and new LTS for a period of time to give a window for clients to cut-over in.

In this case its different as several branches are making public releases. Each cycle the released build was the last successful. This is usually a case of promoting the package from a dev/test repository into the release repository. But that depends on your packaging tool.

This does lead to the case where there may be no release on a given cycle as nothing has changed. Which does complicate automating this.